# Is the GBMV3 object from the H2O server different from the GBMV3 class in the H2O library?

Tags: h2o

We are working with H2O version 3.22.0.1. We created a process in java 10 that communicates with the REST API utilizing jersey version 2.27 with gson 2.3.1. The process invokes ImportFiles, followed by ParseSetup and Parse. Everything works well up until that point. Then the process invokes 3/ModelBuilders/gbm/parameters. From examining the log, it appears that the H2O server responds as expected. However, gson throws a JsonSyntaxException caused by the following:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 4115 path $.parameters

Upon further analysis,  it appears that the H2O server is providing a GBMV3 object with an array of ModelParameterSchemaV3 objects, while the GBMV3 class, as defined in the library that our client uses, extends SharedTreeV3, which extends ModelBuilderSchema, which has a single instance of ModelParametersSchemaV3. There is an apparent discrepancy between the way the GBMV3 object provided by the H2O server is composed, and the way the class is defined in the H2O library. One has an array of ModelParameterSchemaV3 objects, while the other has a single instance of ModelParametersSchemaV3. Is that the case? If so, could you please help us understand what we may be doing wrong, and how to correct it?

See the files located at: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsSlPHvlhJI1hIpB2M5X49J5L-h1qw

Run the H2O server. Import the CSV file in H2O Flow. SetupParse and Parse the data. Run the test procedure. Thank you for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed description. To better understand your problem - would you be able to provide a simplified example of how you are calling H2O-3 using the Java bindings?

You might be hitting a bug so if you are able to give us a reproducer we could expedite a fix for this issue.

Comment: See the files located at:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsSlPHvlhJI1hIpB2M5X49J5L-h1qw
Run the H2O server. Import the CSV file in H2O Flow. SetupParse and Parse the data. Run the test procedure. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to run the test:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.

 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98)
 at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
 at 
Is there a reason why you don't use the REST client provided in h2o-bindings? Example: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-bindings/src/main/java/water/bindings/examples/retrofit/GBM_Example.java

I think you can avoid hitting issues if you use the h2o-binding.

Comment: I was not aware of those methods, and did not know how to use them. Thank you for pointing me to that example. Are there any other web pages that document how to use the h2o-binding library? All I can find are javadocs. I also found the documentation for h2o-genmodel, which promises to provide "a step-by-step guide to creating and implementing POJOs or MOJOs in a Java application." However, in the section that presents sample code for extracting generated models from H2O, there is a "TODO" for java. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Can you please point me to the TODO you found? 

Regarding more documentation - I am not aware of it. I think the example is what we have + the endpoints are documented in Javadoc.

Comment: See the following page: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html
There is no sample code for Java under the heading, "Extracting generated models from H2O".